# Highstock navigator minimum acts weird on series.addPoint when 1+ series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Here's the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/w64j0Ld5/1/

```
for (i; i < data.length; i += 1) {
    series1.addPoint(data[i], false, true);
    series2.addPoint(data[i], false, true);
}
chart.redraw();
```

Notice that I have 2 data series and I'm adding data dynamically. Watch the 'chart min' change as you add data....makes perfect sense....new data in, old data out.

Now hit the 'All' filter (or slide the left handle of the navigator to the left) and watch the chart min revert back to what it was originally....but I don't see the old chart min in the chart...

With one data series, it works perfectly: http://jsfiddle.net/w64j0Ld5/3/ (you can't slide the left handle of the navigator to the left as the old data is GONE as it should be!)

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Something's wrong with the data being the same in both series. Here's an example when the data is not identical: http://jsfiddle.net/w64j0Ld5/4/

Comment: Yes, it's better to use copy of the data arrays, instead of the original ones, since Highcharts may modify that array points: http://jsfiddle.net/w64j0Ld5/5/

Comment: yep, works like a charm if you use 2 different arrays. in hindsight that makes sense. but i wonder why setting useUTC = false breaks it - http://jsfiddle.net/w64j0Ld5/6/